# java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap, Unable to trace exact location

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, runtimeexception, bitmapfactory

Inside my application I am using Bitmap at multiple location/Activity, and recycle all of them whenever corresponding activity destroy.
    I have mentioned complete stack trace of exception from there it's clear exception occurred due to still using of recycled Bitmap but I am unable to trace that class or bitmap. Can any one help me how to trace location of crash inside my application

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@42d3c090
       at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1084)
       at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:844)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:490)
       at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1019)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2156)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:769)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2377)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2249)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This is very first time I post/ask question so please ignore language.

Comment: You may need to show some relevant code.

Comment: @ci_ How can he show releavant code if there may be multiple packages and the logs dont show where from the exception comes???

Answer (score 0):

Write following bit of code to prevent such exception while using bitmap in canvas.

```
if (mBitmap != null && !mBitmap.isRecycled()) {
    //Write code to show bitmap to canvas
}else{
    //write code to recreate bitmap from source
    //Write code to show bitmap to canvas
}
```

Comment: where to write if i dont see where from that exception was thrown?

Comment: @CodeToLife you need to write when you are not more using bitmap. Like you can write in end of method or when your fragment is not visible.

Comment: Yes, but ... I mean there is multiple use of such bitmaps and their recycles after the use but one of such animations or drawables(also a lot) or whatever uses bitmaps (ex- or implicitely) does through this error. And I cannot trace what peace of code drops that. That logcat doesn make sense. I would like to find some alternative tool such profiler , probably. I think this is a very specific  topic and I ve starred it.

Comment: I think you can use "https://github.com/square/leakcanary" to identify your leaks. This might useful to identify.